# Permission denied when creating shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I'm having problems creating new shapefiles - in QGIS 2.14.20 any new fields I create and any associated data are not saved.  I've now got the same problem in QGIS 3.0, but there I get a message saying layer creation failed.  There is an error message but it just seems to say 'warning  :'   But under OGR I get:

2018-05-10T10:44:30    WARNING Creation of OGR data source test.shp failed: Failed to create file test.shp: Permission denied

I am running on an iMac High Sierra 10.13.4.  I also sometimes can't save projects.  I am the only user of this machine and have admin privileges, and am trying to save the shapefiles and projects locally.

Comment: Navigate to the folder you are trying to save in and can you create any files there?

Comment: yes, no problem, its just on the local disk

Comment: actually the creation fails before I give a file path

Answer (score 18):

Before trying to save the file, click on the folder button at the right of the filename entery box and select a writeable folder for the save.

Comment: This was my problem. I just typed a name like `Nodes` and got the `Failed to create file Nodes.shp: Permission denied` error. What worked was clicking the `...` button next to `File name` field and selecting a writable directory for the shape file there.

Answer (score 5):

Just like said above, when entering the name of the `Shapefile`, click on the button **(...)** on the right hand side, and choose the location folder to save.

I was having the same issue, as per default it was saving to a random folder, and when I chose the right folder on the server it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I clicked the `...` button next to "File name field" and selected a writable directory for the shapefile, the layer got created.

Answer (score 1):

I got some professional help in the end to fix this.  It seemed to be a problem with pathways because the QGIS3 install for mac had overwritten some settings.  A 'deep clean' uninstall and fresh install and I am almost up and running again.