# No "Save As..." in QGIS 3.2?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, csv

I have been trying to save my CSV file using the "Save As" from a right click as suggested on many websites, but I literally can't see this button. See my picture attached (on the left my QGIS 3.2 interface, on the right a blog extract based on QGIS 2.8), is that a bug?

I am trying to do that to save my data with another CRS that would match my shapefile so that I can calculate my buffer with a unit different from my CSV file.

[image]

Comment: Did you try the "Save Features As" button?

Comment: I did, but got an error message: Export to vector file failed.
Error: Creation of layer failed (OGR error: Failed to create file NewFileName.shp: Permission denied)

Comment: @Laure It sounds like there are some other file management issues going on there, meaning QGIS can't read the folder you're trying to save to - browse to an explicit location and name the file vs. taking any default locations / names.

Comment: Could be related to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282434/permission-denied-when-creating-shapefile

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's been renamed to "save features as". Your "permission denied" error is a result of trying to save the output somewhere which cannot be written to. Try clicking the "..." button and setting a different output folder.