# Unable to create shapefile layer, read only file system

Tags: qgis, shapefile, editing

I'm using QGIS version 3.16.4 Hannover and since I downloaded it, I haven't been able to create a shapefile layer or use any editing tools. When i try to make a shapefile it gives an error saying:

> Failed to create layer: failed to create file line.shp: read-only file system.

So I assume that I have to change the file system from read-only, into something I can edit. However I can't find anything concerning this. I tried different file coding, geometry and type. I use a map of The Netherlands and I've tried both WGS 84 and Amersfoort/ RD New. I don't have much experience with QGIS. How can I fix this?

Comment: Show us the file path.  QGIS often defaults to saving things in a read only system folder

Comment: Also what operating system are you using? Is this your computer or a work / network computer ?  See also: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282434/permission-denied-when-creating-shapefile

Answer (score 2):

Change the path of where you're saving the file.  It's very likely that you are trying to save the file in a read-only system folder.

Press the button highlighted in blue:

[image]

You'll likely see that the default path is in a read-only folder:

[image]

Just select a path to your Documents or somewhere else where you have full read/write access.

Comment: Ah okay, where can i find this?

Comment: Check updated answer with screenshots. I assume you're using Windows? I added WIN10 as your OS as a tag. Please change that if you're running on a different OS.