Error saving KML as shapefile using QGIS
I have imported a .kml as vector, worked on that and saved after some addition in the data. The error message received is:

Export to vector file failed.
Error: Creation of layer failed (OGR error: Failed to create file (file name).shp: Permission denied)

How and where should I save the shapefile?

You need to list in details exactly all the steps you did in order to export the layer or provide some screenshot.
From you description, I suppose you didn't specify, in the "Save Vector Layer as..." dialog window, which folder you want to export the layer into.
https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-new-layers-from-an-existing-layer

Make sure you specify a folder path, not just the file name https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/284259/2856

And apart from that: make sure you have writing permission in this path
